# Using Docker, how to change bash version?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-build

Does anyone know of a reliable way to switch between Bash version 3 and Bash version 4 in a Docker container?

For testing purposes, I want to run one container with version 3 and one with version 4, however technically I don't need to switch versions, just need to build an image with the two different versions.

```
ARG base_image
FROM $base_image

RUN # install bash here

ENTRYPOINT bash -c "whatevs"
```

in my case, I care most about Debian/Ubuntu base images. But I suppose it would be interesting to find a generic bash install command that could work for most if not all *nix machines.

Btw, the above syntax is the way to create a generic base image, and you would build it like so:

```
docker build -t foo --build-arg base_image="$base_image"  .
```

Comment: Haven't tried it, but I'm assuming you could download 3 from source and compile, specifying options so that it doesn't conflict with 4, and then invoke it as per normal `/path/to/install/bash -c "command"`?

Comment: Bash's compatibility mode might help: `shopt -s compat31`

Comment: I suggest you add your Dockerfile to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus good idea, I updated the OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are already [official bash images](https://hub.docker.com/_/bash/) for all the versions, so you can just:

```
docker run -it bash:4.4 -c 'whatevs'
```

Or:

```
docker run -it bash:3.2 -c 'whatevs'
```

If for some reason you can't use the official images, building a single image with two versions of bash will probably require that you install at least one from source.  For example, you could start with `ubuntu:18.04`, which has bash 4.4.19, and then build and install another version into `/usr/local`.

---

If you want to build and install Bash yourself, you're going to need:

- A functioning development environment (C compiler, `make`, `autoconf`, etc)
- The bash sources

This is actually a great situation for making use of a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/), since you don't necessarily want that build environment cluttering up the final image.  Here's one way of tackling it:

```
##
## Build bash 3
##

FROM ubuntu:18.04 as bash_3
ARG bash_3_version=3.2.57
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential curl bison

WORKDIR /tmp
RUN curl -o bash-${bash_3_version}.tar.gz \
  http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-${bash_3_version}.tar.gz
RUN tar xf bash-${bash_3_version}.tar.gz

WORKDIR /tmp/bash-${bash_3_version}
RUN ./configure --prefix=/opt/bash3
RUN make EXEEXT=3
RUN make install EXEEXT=3

##
## Build bash 4
##

FROM ubuntu:18.04 as bash_4
ARG bash_4_version=4.4.18
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential curl bison

WORKDIR /tmp
RUN curl -o bash-${bash_4_version}.tar.gz \
  http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-${bash_4_version}.tar.gz
RUN tar xf bash-${bash_4_version}.tar.gz

WORKDIR /tmp/bash-${bash_4_version}
RUN ./configure --prefix=/opt/bash4
RUN make EXEEXT=4
RUN make install EXEEXT=4

##
## Build the final image
##

FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV PATH=/opt/bash4/bin:/opt/bash3/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
COPY --from=bash_3 /opt/bash3 /opt/bash3
COPY --from=bash_4 /opt/bash4 /opt/bash4
```

If you use this to build an image called `basher`, you can then...

```
$ docker run -it --rm basher bash3 --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)   
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

And:

```
$ docker run -it --rm basher bash4 --version             
GNU bash, version 4.4.18(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: yes thanks, I upvoted, but I should have made my question more clear. Most likely the base image will be something other than bash:x, so I will need to install bash after inheriting from another base image. See the comment in the Dockerfile example.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example that uses multi-stage builds to produce an image (based on `ubuntu`) with two bash versions.