# How to upgrade bash via a dockerfile?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I have a base image with bash 4.2 and I'd like to upgrade it to 5.1

I've attempted to unzip it and then set the path variable to that folder as such:

```
RUN curl -o /tmp/bash-5.1.tar.gz ${BASH_URL}/bash/5.1/bash-5.1.tar.gz \
  && tar -xvf /tmp/bash-5.1.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin \
  && rm /tmp/bash-5.1.tar.gz
ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin/bash-5.1:$PATH
```

However when I build the image all containers from it still run bash 4.2. I also can't find commands like `grep` in the `.tar.gz` package despite it being off the official site, so I'm not truly sure of where I'm even meant to set the `PATH`. This is the first layer of the `tarball`:

```
ABOUT-NLS    bashline.c    conftypes.h    findcmd.c  lib           parse.y         shell.c      unwind_prot.c
aclocal.m4   bashline.h    copy_cmd.c     findcmd.h  list.c        patchlevel.h    shell.h      unwind_prot.h
alias.c      bashtypes.h   COPYING        flags.c    locale.c      pathexp.c       sig.c        variables.c
alias.h      bracecomp.c   cross-build    flags.h    m4            pathexp.h       sig.h        variables.h
array.c      braces.c      CWRU           general.c  mailcheck.c   pathnames.h.in  siglist.c    version.c
arrayfunc.c  builtins      dispose_cmd.c  general.h  mailcheck.h   pcomplete.c     siglist.h    xmalloc.c
arrayfunc.h  builtins.h    dispose_cmd.h  hashcmd.c  make_cmd.c    pcomplete.h     stringlib.c  xmalloc.h
array.h      ChangeLog     doc            hashcmd.h  make_cmd.h    pcomplib.c      subst.c      Y2K
assoc.c      CHANGES       error.c        hashlib.c  Makefile.in   po              subst.h      y.tab.c
assoc.h      command.h     error.h        hashlib.h  MANIFEST      POSIX           support      y.tab.h
AUTHORS      COMPAT        eval.c         include    mksyntax.c    print_cmd.c     syntax.h
bashansi.h   config-bot.h  examples       input.c    NEWS          quit.h          test.c
bashhist.c   config.h.in   execute_cmd.c  input.h    nojobs.c      RBASH           test.h
bashhist.h   config-top.h  execute_cmd.h  INSTALL    NOTES         README          tests
bashintl.h   configure     expr.c         jobs.c     parser-built  redir.c         trap.c
bashjmp.h    configure.ac  externs.h      jobs.h     parser.h      redir.h         trap.h
```

I would've expected to see things like `grep`, `echo` and `chmod` etc.

My goal is just to be able to build a dockerfile and have it run bash 5.1. Everything else in the file works except this section.

Comment: What exactly does the tarball contain? The `PATH` you assigned expects it to contain a directory `bash-5.1` which should contain a binary called literally `bash` in order for this to actually work.  I'm going to guess you misunderstand how `PATH` works; but feel free to [edit] to clarify your question and ping me if the duplicate is not correct.

Comment: @tripleee I got the idea to use `PATH` from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51030884/using-docker-how-to-change-bash-version

I'm not too clear on what exactly I'm doing here as I can't find anything on the internet on upgrading bash in an image.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51030884/using-docker-how-to-change-bash-version

Comment: Why do you need a newer version of bash in particular?  My general experience is that many things can be rewritten using only [POSIX shell features](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) (in which case they can use even the minimal `/bin/sh` in Alpine images), and those that can't are often easier to express in a higher-level language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tarball you installed doesn't contain a `bash` binary at all; it contains the C sources which need to be compiled and installed before you have a new `bash`.

Also, if the binary is called `bash` and you install it in `/usr/local/bin/bash`, your `PATH` should contain `/usr/local/bin`, not the actual name of the individual binary. (See [Should PATH contain directories or full paths to binaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285676/should-path-contain-directories-or-full-paths-to-binaries)) ... but chances are it already does.

So, in very very brief

```
RUN curl -o /tmp/bash-5.1.tar.gz ${BASH_URL}/bash/5.1/bash-5.1.tar.gz \
  && tar -xvf /tmp/bash-5.1.tar.gz -C /tmp \
  && cd /tmp/bash-5.1 \
  && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local \
  && make \
  && make install
# Probably not actually necessary
ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

but read the `INSTALL` file in the tarball and probably study how exactly your distro's Bash is built so you can supply the same configuration parameters etc.

What exactly will work depends also somewhat on your target platform.

The installed binary is named `bash`, not `grep`. If you want to install a new version of `grep`, that's a separate package (GNU `coreutils` if you are on Linux).  Similarly for the external command `chmod`. `echo` is a built-in command in the shell so it is not compiled into a separate binary.

For many Linux distros, the absolutely simplest way to install a newer Bash is to find a binary repository which contains an installable, packaged newer version which you can just `apt install` or similar.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 It could be either. A `Dockerfile` can contain arguments and variables of its own, which are then visible to any shell script snippets in `RUN` statements etc. The OP should probably have included the full URL in the question in the first place to make it clearer.